# How to open vscode with vscode://vscode-remote with devcontainers?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I am using Locator.js that is a great way to open file from a browser by using `vscode://file/.....file.ts` protocol.

I also know how to open the remote-ssh, I managed to google that, but so far, I had no luck in opening a devcontainer project, that is already opened in vscode.

I found some examples [here](https://grep.app/search?q=vscode-remote%3A//dev) and It did open the vscode, but it doesn't open the project in a right way, it just opens that one file, and if the vscode is already open with that project, it ignores is and opens a new window with that one file.

How to open? Also, is there a way to debug from inside of vscode to see what is the URI for the given file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, VS Code doesn't directly support opening DevContainer projects with a `vscode://` URI in the same straightforward way as local or SSH remote files. However, you can achieve a similar result by using the Command Palette or VS Code's CLI.

**Quick Solution:**

1. **Manually**: Use the Command Palette (`Ctrl+Shift+P` or `Cmd+Shift+P` on macOS) and select **Remote-Containers: Open Folder in Container...** to open your project in its DevContainer.
2. **CLI Approach**: Although not directly through a `vscode://` link, you can open a terminal and use VS Code's command line interface to open your project in a container:

   ```bash
   code --folder-uri vscode-remote://dev-container+<containerName>/<pathToProject>
   ```

   Replace `<containerName>` with your container's name and `<pathToProject>` with the path to your project.